# How to automatically deduce literal size at static type?

Tags: arrays, string, d, literals

If I initialize an static variable declared with 'auto' using string literal - it's type is automatically deduced as `immutable(char)[]` which is a structure of both it's size and pointer to string content. Here is an example:

```
static auto str = "St";
```

Possible structure of the above data:

```
dd DstringSize
dd pstringraw ;points to string
...
db string...
```

However if I initialize one using constant size then only the literal data is stored and the size of it becomes part of the type:

```
static immutable(char)[2] str = "St";
```

Possibly looks like this (note that there is no any terminating character explicitly appended):

```
db string...
```

So my question is how can I both store the string literal size in the type and deduce it's size automatically like in 'C++'. If I use this construct:

```
static immutable(char)[] str = "Sj";
```

It's equivalent to the first one and have a type of `immutable(char)[]` but I want it's type to be automatically deduced by string literal size and to be `immutable(char)[2]`.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Note that I'm new to this language. I hope you understand what I mean. For the results of the code however - I'm sure because I used IDA Pro to check them.

Comment: `T[]` and `T[2]` are semantically different. `T[]` is a slice and has reference semantics. `T[2]` is a fixed-sized array and has value semantics.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a way to do this built in to the language, so here's a little hack I drafted up:

```
import std.traits : ForeachType;

/// Build a compile-time static array out of `val`.
auto ctStaticArray(alias val)() {
  alias T = ForeachType!(typeof(val));
  enum N  = val.length;
  return cast(T[N]) val;
}

static auto str = ctStaticArray!"st";
static auto arr = ctStaticArray!([1,2,3]);

pragma(msg, typeof(str)); // immutable(char)[2]
pragma(msg, typeof(arr)); // int[3]
```

I haven't tested it very thouroughly, but it should be able to take an array literal and convert it to a static array.
Its not as clean as just saying `static auto st = "st"`, but at least you don't have to manually determine what the length should be declared as.

Comment: It work mostly. However I checked the compiled code with IDA and it seems that 'ctStaticArray' generates dead function (which is never instanced) with a dead copy of the string passed to it, strangely zero-terminated. Any guesses why so? Maybe compiler mistake? I've set all optimizations turned on.

Comment: Weird. According to http://dlang.org/arrays.html#strings, D strings are specifically _not_ '\0' terminated.

Comment: All-right. Instead of function I used variable template and it now works without extra garbage I think.

Comment: @rcorre String literals are always zero-terminated in D, but the `'\0'` is one passed the end of the string, and it's not actually considered part of the string (i.e. it would be at `"foo"[$]`, which would result in a `RangeError`). So, you can pass a string literal to a C function which expects a null-terminated strings, but for any other string, you have to append the `'\0'` yourself (e.g. via `std.string.stringz`), and no D code is going to treat strings as null-terminated.

Comment: Or use `toStringz` or `fromStringz`.